# ‘cross’ must not exceed sampling size in r

Tags: r, svm

I am trying to tune a dataset using the SVM model.

```
set.seed(1142325)
tune.out <- tune(svm, fnlDat_Train$response~fnlDat_Train$is + fnlDat_Train$qh + fnlDat_Train$sci + fnlDat_Train$bw+fnlDat_Train$dtj+fnlDat_Train$ent+fnlDat_Train$ox+fnlDat_Train$ku+fnlDat_Train$np+fnlDat_Train$bnf+fnlDat_Train$ypz+fnlDat_Train$tdt+fnlDat_Train$sb+fnlDat_Train$id+fnlDat_Train$wc+fnlDat_Train$xt+fnlDat_Train$xt+fnlDat_Train$zwp, data=fnlDat_Train, kernel="linear", ranges=list(cost=c(0.001,0.01,1,100)))
summary(tune.out)
```

I got an error message

```
‘cross’ must not exceed sampling size!
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Just a comment, because you have `data = fnlDat_Train`, you don't need to put `fnlDat_Train$` in front of every variable in the formula.

Comment: Can you post an example that reproduces your error or `dput` your data? It seems that the number of folds for the cross-validation exceeds the number of observations in your data. I suppose that the `cross` parameter is set to 10 by default.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by tuning svm (or RandomForest or linear or any other tuned method). Remove the tune part so it's now a normal function without tuning and it runs fine, no errors.